# SetEnvIf Referer in htaccess

Tags: php, html, linux, .htaccess

I'm trying to get my htaccess file to block all traffic unless the link is clicked from a local file called premiere.htm. This is what I have right now and it's not working... What am I doing wrong?

```
SetEnvIf Referer .*(premiere.htm)$ let_me_in
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=let_me_in
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers won't send a `referer` header if the link is accessed from an HTML document loaded from `file://`. If you use Chrome and open the developer tools before following the link, you will be able to see the request headers - the browser is likely not passing this info for local files.